# Windows 10 shows themed images on login screen, then opens browser to page related to image after login - how can I prevent it?

Tags: windows-10, login, login-screen

On the login screen they show pictures, and I have to admit, sometimes they are nice but I do not want them. After I log in, windows 10 starts the browser and it goes to a page related to the image they used on the login screen.

I attached the screenshot of the browser that was opened up automatically after I logged in this morning.

How can I turn off this feature? I did not click on the text displayed on the login screen.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 Settings, Personalization, Lock Screen.

In Lock Screen settings, turn OFF (uncheck) Get fun facts, tips .... on your Lock Screen.

That setting should be OFF for a plainer approach to Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you. I turned it off and I am going to keep an eye on it to see if it comes back.